# Mixed management in C++

Tags: c++-cli, managed

I have added a class to my program and tested it. I was really surprised that there was any real errors. Here is the code:

```
#pragma once
#include "Iingredient.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

ref class Recipe{
private:
    string partsName;
    vector<Iingredient> ing;
public:
    Recipe(){}

};
```

And here are the errors:

> Error 23  error C4368: cannot define 'partsName' as a member of managed
>   'Recipe': mixed types are not
>   supported c:\users\user\documents\visual studio
>   2010\projects\smestras2_l1\Recipe.h   10  1   file2_L1
>
> Error 24  error C4368: cannot define 'ing' as a member of managed
>   'Recipe': mixed types are not
>   supported c:\users\user\documents\visual studio
>   2010\projects\smestras2_l1\Recipe.h   11  1   file2_L1

I googled a bit and found out that its about managed and unmanaged code.
How to fix this? Is it related with manged and unmanaged code or not? if so how?

Comment: don't do `using namespace std;` it,s eventually going to lead you down roads you don't want to go down.

Comment: Do you have a question? SO isn't a blog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When defining `ref class Recipe`, you made it *managed*. But `std::string` and `std::vector` are umanaged types. You are trying to declare native variables in managed class, but it is not allowed.

Seems, you are novice in C++. Just, don't use C++/CLI. Consider C#, if you target .Net or unmanaged C++.

Comment: +1 Sound advice to keep out of C++-cli for beginners, it is much more complex than either C# or C++ (which are complex enough on their own)

Comment: So to make this work I just need to delete the `ref`to make it a normal C++ class. I used and add class button in visual studio and it generated the class like this, so I thought it had to be correct. Thanks.

Comment: what is the usage 'ref' word in-front of class anyway ? @Povylas

Answer (score 12):

I agree with others: you shouldn't use C++/CLI in most circumstances, you should use C# (or another "normal" managed language) for that (assuming you want to write a .Net application). C++/CLI is useful mostly in special circumstances, like interoperating between managed and unmanaged code.

If you're sure you want use C++/CLI, you can't put native classes into managed ones. But you can put *pointers* to native classes there:

```
ref class Recipe{
private:
    string* partsName;
    vector<Iingredient>* ing;
};
```

The code above works. But you have to keep in mind that those are normal native C++ pointers and that means you have to manually `delete` them. To do that property, you should read about how destructors and finalizers work in C++/CLI.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use unmanaged types in a managed class, `ref` keyword, because the heap and the managed heap are two different types of memory. To solve this specific problem you can use a managed string type (`System::String^`). The carrot tells the compiler that the type is a handle to a managed class.

Another way of going about this problem is to use pointers, that way the pointer will be on the managed heap, and the actual memory for that object will be in the standard unmanaged heap, which is where `Recipe` is located.

To construct your `Recipe` class you would have to do

```
Recipe^ recipe = gcnew Recipe();
```

Comment: if i want to use "System::String^" -> should i use a statement of "include <String> as well at the upperside of the code or should i use a statement "using namespace something" ?  @Patrizio....

Answer (score 1):

With no idea of c++-cli, I can try and guess that the problem is that you are defining a reference type and trying to use C++ types inside (a `std::string` field) rather than whatever the equivalent managed type is (`String`?).

The reason why this can be problematic is that it mixes resource management approaches. Reference types are intended to be used out of a garbage collector, and unless you implement a destructor or `IDisposable` will just be ignored once proven that the last reference is lost. On the other hand, to be able to manage the memory in the internal field the `std::string` destructor must be called.